# How do I resolve 'No suitable cloud connector found' error when testing CloudFactory method with JUnit?

Tags: exception, testing, junit, cloud

I have one method

```
public Cloud cloud() {
    return new CloudFactory().getCloud();
}
```

For which I am writing test case

```
@Test
public void testCloud() {
    cloudConfig = new CloudConfig();
    Cloud cloudBean = cloudConfig.cloud();
    assertFalse(Objects.isNull(cloudBean));
}
```

I am expecting this test case to be passed but its giving me an error

No suitable cloud connector found
org.springframework.cloud.CloudException: No suitable cloud connector found